# Automatic Recognition of the languages on InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have to make an index, there'll be two languages for this index but sometimes, wrong language words are forgotten in the other index, I can't read back everything, they are too many pages, so I'm looking for a way to apply an automatic recognition of the languages in Adobe Indesign.

I found nothing :/

Is There a way to do that, mainly in Adobe Indesign (cs5.5), or in other ways?

Comment: Not enough information. Are your texts tagged correctly with their language? How are you creating *two* indexes? How are you currently determining which word goes where?

Comment: Hum my bad, i'll try to explain better.
The first index is in french and completely true.
The Second is in german and this come from a Database i import to Adobe ID with easycatalog;

Comment: Woops, here the real answer... : 

Hum my bad, i'll try to explain better.
The first index is in french and completely true.
The Second is in german and this come from a Database i import to Adobe ID with easycatalog.
The indexes are from differents ID files. (but with the same template.)
Do you think we can compare each "same" field to check if they are similar?

Thanks for your answer, it's greatly appreciated.